# Creating buffer for New Zealand map using QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, new-zealand

I am currently working on a map of New Zealand, and would like to put 100km buffers around some of my polygons. However, whenever I try to add a CRS layer in order to do it, the shapes just disappear off my map! Or when I do manage to get them to stay, they are in degrees instead of kilometers.

Does New Zealand just not have good and usable CRS?

Comment: New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000

Comment: What software are you using, and what is the CRS of your source data?

Comment: @Hamish, I am using qgis 3.18.3 and the source data is EPSG:4167 (which puts it just over Italy on my map now)

Comment: That won't be the right source projection if it's displaying over Italy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find out a metric projection for New Zealand. @FelixIP made a suggestion in the comments. You can look at this link about [New Zealand projections](https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/datums-projections-and-heights/projections).

Once you get the CRS you need to change the layer projection and maybe the project projection.

Comment: Ahh I see.... Thank you!